# ColdFusion Builder validate against railo friendly operators "==", "!=" etc

Tags: coldfusion, railo, coldfusionbuilder

Anyone know a way to update coldfusion builder's validation rules to allow for Railo operators like "==", etc.?

Comment: ColdFusion Builder can see those operators within cfscript. You are referring to CFML tag support?

Comment: Yes. I was thinking maybe adding the cfeclipse dictionary for railo would work, but that's a hard thing to track down. Can't find a stand alone version anywhere.

Comment: I think those operators work in ColdFusion too, no? But yes, CFB marks those lines red. I guess they'll fix this in 2.0 ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/denuno/cfml.dictionary is where you can find the whole of the CFML Dictionary project using in cfeclipse and donated to ColdFusion Builder I believe.

You should just be able to give CFBuilder the railo dictionary from the dictionary folder in the repository. How you give CFBuilder the dictionary.... I'm not sure, but it should be relatively straight forward.